# OpenCV error when using Rodrigues function in Qtcreator

Tags: qt, opencv, rotation, qt-creator, runtime-error

I encounter a problem in QtCreator when using function cv::Rodrigues from OpenCV.
I always get run-time error while converting Rotation matrix to rotation vector using rodrigues.
I don't have such a problem when going from rot vector to rot matrix but it sucks vice versa.
Here is a simple code using this function. 
It's well mentioning that it works out in Visual studio.

```
        cv::Mat R(3,3,CV_32F);

        R.at<float>(0,0)=0;
        R.at<float>(0,1)=0;
        R.at<float>(0,2)=1;
        R.at<float>(1,0)=0;
        R.at<float>(1,1)=1;
        R.at<float>(1,2)=0;
        R.at<float>(2,0)=-1;
        R.at<float>(2,1)=0;
        R.at<float>(2,2)=0;

        cv::Mat rvec_result;
        cv::Rodrigues(R,rvec_result);
```

R is a 3x3 matrix representing 90 degree rotation around Y axis.
When I trace it in debug mode, I get Segmentation fault(SIGSEGV) at calling rodrigues().

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.1 and my system is 64bits.
Can any one help me to cope with this problem?

Thanks in advance.